# Error with networx.descendants() when nodes have tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am using networkx with Python 3.4, and I get a weird error when I try to find the reachable nodes. I think it has something to do with an optional property of the nodes, that I previously set. This minimal code replicates the error:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
nodes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]                                      
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)                                                
G.add_edge("A", "B")
G.add_edge("A", "C")                                                   
G.add_edge("A", "D")                                                   
G.add_edge("B", "E")

for node in nodes :
        G[node]['occurrences'] = 1                                     

print("Now computing nodes reachable from \"A\"...")
reachableNodes = nx.descendants(G, "A")                                
print("List of reachable nodes:", reachableNodes)
```

The output is:

```
Now computing nodes reachable from "A"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exampleStackOverflow.py", line 17, in <module>
    reachableNodes = nx.descendants(G, "A")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/dag.py", line 42, in descendants
    des = set(nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=source).keys()) - set([source])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/generic.py", line 239, in shortest_path_length
    paths=nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/unweighted.py", line 63, in single_source_shortest_path_length
    nextlevel.update(G[v]) # add neighbors of v
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 407, in __getitem__
    return self.adj[n]
KeyError: 'occurrences'
```

Now, if I comment the lines when I set the tag 'occurrences', I get the expected result:

```
Now computing nodes reachable from "A"...
List of reachable nodes: {'B', 'D', 'C', 'E'}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Gerrat's approach using a custom node class will work.  But the recommended way is to use `G.node` to store node data.  You got it almost correct.  This is the problem code

```
for node in nodes :
    G[node]['occurrences'] = 1 # INCORRECT, corrupts data structure

for node in nodes :
    G.node[node]['occurrences'] = 1 # CORRECT
```

Working example

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
nodes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edge("A", "B")
G.add_edge("A", "C")
G.add_edge("A", "D")
G.add_edge("B", "E")

for n in nodes :
        G.node[n]['occurrences'] = 1

print("Now computing nodes reachable from \"A\"...")
reachableNodes = nx.descendants(G, "A")
print("List of reachable nodes:", reachableNodes)

for n in reachableNodes:
    print n,G.node[n]


#OUTPUT
Now computing nodes reachable from "A"...
('List of reachable nodes:', set(['C', 'B', 'E', 'D']))
C {'occurrences': 1}
B {'occurrences': 1}
E {'occurrences': 1}
D {'occurrences': 1}
```

There is more information at https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html#adding-attributes-to-graphs-nodes-and-edges on how to set graph, node, and edge attributes.

Comment: I added a link to the relevant networkx tutorial section.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine what a node is a little closer:

```
for node in nodes :
    print(node, type(G[node]), G[node].keys())
```

You'll get:

```
('A', <type 'dict'>, ['C', 'B', 'D'])
('B', <type 'dict'>, ['A', 'E'])
('C', <type 'dict'>, ['A'])
('D', <type 'dict'>, ['A'])
('E', <type 'dict'>, ['B'])
```

You can see that `G[node]` is a dictionary with keys corresponding to other nodes it shares an edge with.  You're bypassing its normal Node creation routine, and  insert a node called `occurrences` into the mix, joined by edge to each other node.  The reason I say `trying to` is that this Node isn't setup properly, and won't function correctly when added this way.

If you want to store additional properties on your Nodes, you could setup a Node class, for example:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, letter):
        self.letter = letter

    def __str__(self):
        return self.letter
```

...then:

```
nodes = [Node(l) for l in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]]
```

you can now attach any property you like to these nodes (but not to `G[node]`).

Comment: I see! Thanks for the clarification, I had totally overlooked that part. I thought that, like edges, nodes could store different properties without having to create a wrapper class. I will correct my code.